# Add more than 65535 entries jar in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I created a custom semantic similarity between sentences algorithm. Project created 65535 entries jar as it contains 100,000 words. I added custom jar to my spring boot project using "mvn install:install-file" and created boot jar, but whenever i run project i am getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get nested archive for entry BOOT-INF/lib/semantics-1.0.jar
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchives(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:72)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open nested jar file 'BOOT-INF/lib/semantics-1.0.jar'
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:252)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:237)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchive(JarFileArchive.java:104)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Zip64 archives are not supported
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryEndRecord.getNumberOfRecords(CentralDirectoryEndRecord.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries.visitStart(JarFileEntries.java:91)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryParser.visitStart(CentralDirectoryParser.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryParser.parse(CentralDirectoryParser.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromFileEntry(JarFile.java:290)

 at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.createJarFileFromEntry(JarFile.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.getNestedJarFile(JarFile.java:248)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: If I correctly understand, it is DATA (i.e. not java code), so why `jar` is required? ... BTW i create 1GB Zip by Java (slow, but works)

Comment: yes it is data, not java code. It is very cumbersome if your build take 3 hours to compile every time you change your code. Any suggestion can help here

Comment: _Zip64 archives are not supported_ create a normal zip/jar instead?

Comment: Edited my question. Kindly review now.

Comment: I'd seriously reconsider how you're dealing with your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2895

The key error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Zip64 archives are not supported
```

55mb does not require the Zip64 format, you probably should change how you create your file.

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot will not support more than 65534 files in the jar. Here is the their code.

```
public int getNumberOfRecords() {
        long numberOfRecords = Bytes.littleEndianValue(this.block, this.offset + 10, 2);
        if (numberOfRecords == 0xFFFF) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Zip64 archives are not supported");
        }
        return (int) numberOfRecords;
    }
```

Since its data file, keep it outside jar, which will reduce the build time as well.

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot 2.2 will support zip64 jars [Github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/16091)

Answer (score -1):

I know it is not a good practice but my spring project is working fine now as I included my dependencies whole package to spring project rather than creating a jar of that dependency and then importing it.